# Using node_modules from Windows on Linux Jenkins CI...good or bad?

Tags: node.js, angular, jenkins, karma-runner

We have a Angular 4 project with the typical, local node_module (angular-cli, rxjs, karma, jasmine, phantomjs-prebuilt etc). The development machines run on Windows. We want to run tests for the app on Jenkins CI, installed on Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS.

Is there a "best practice" how to handle the node_modules?

- Is it good or bad to add node_modules to the GIT repository?
- Aren't some packages platform-dependent, ie. the package commited from a Windows machine would be useless on Ubuntu (I'm thinking specifically PhantomJS-prebuilt)
- If we need to install all required npm packages on the CI server, wouldn't those need to be globally installed?

So far I've seen plenty of "using Jenkins with Karma" blog posts, but they all run Jenkins on the local development machine. Not much help there.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's normal in a lot of companies that developers coding in windows and Jenkins builds in Unix, it's not a problem.

It's not a good practice to upload node_modules folder to your git repository.The best practice is to upload your artifacts to an artifact repository(Nexus, Jfrog Artifactory...) and write these dependencies in your package.json.

When you build npm install in Jenkins will be download these artifacts from your artifact repository (Nexus, Jfrog Artifactory...).

Also when you deploy artifacts, these artifacts will be deployed to your Nexus or Artifactory.

Comment: Went with git-ignoring /node_modules/, and using npm install in Jenkins to get the required packages. Thanks @trisquel.

Comment: Please don't upload node_modules to your git repository.

Comment: @rodelarivera why are you negative voting my response if I worte the same as your comment? "t's not a good practice to upload node_modules"

Comment: My bad, I've misread the text. I'm trying to vote up but it says that's locked until the answer is edited.

Comment: @rodelarivera No problem mate.